# Chinese Restaurant Process: Expected cardinality (number of customers) of each block (table)?

Tags: stochastic-processes, combinatorics, dirichlet-process, nonparametric-bayes

**Short version of the question**: The Chinese Restaurant Process defines a distribution over partitions of $[T] := \{1, ...., T\}$. What is the expected cardinality of the $t$th block, where $t \in \{1, ..., T\}$?

**Long version of the question**: Suppose we have a Chinese Restaurant Process with parameter $\alpha$. As background, the $CRP(\alpha)$ specifies a conditional distribution of the form:

$$p(z_t = k|z_1, ..., z_{t-1}) = \begin{cases}
\frac{\alpha}{\alpha + t - 1} & k = K_{t-1} + 1\\
\frac{N_{t-1,k}}{\alpha + t - 1} & k \leq K_{t-1}
\end{cases}$$

where $N_{t-1, k}$ is the integer number of customers at the $k$th table after the $t-1$ customer has been seated, and $K_{t-1}$ is the integer number of non-empty tables.

For each partition of $T$ customers, I can write a $T$-dimensional vector $N_T$ of how many customers are at each table. For instance, if $T=3$, the sample space of $N_t$ is $\mathcal{N}_T := \{(3, 0, 0), (2, 1, 0), (1, 2, 0), (1, 1, 1) \}$. Any of these partitions has some probability mass, given by the CRP:

$$P(N_T) = \frac{\alpha^{T-1} \prod_{k=1}^K N_{T, k}!}{(\alpha+1)_{T -1 \uparrow 1}}$$

where the denominator is the so-called rising factorial, defined as:
$$x_{M \uparrow a} := \prod_{m=0}^{M-1}(x + ma)$$

My question is: what is the expected value of this random $T$-dimensional vector?

$$\mathbb{E}_{N_T}[N_T] = \sum_{N_T \in \mathcal{N}_T} N_T P(N_T)$$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is some ambiguity as to what is table $k$, but I am going to assume that table $k$ is the $k$th table encountered in a sequential sampling as you have mentioned. That is,
$$
N_k = \sum_{t=1}^T 1\{z_t = k\} \implies \mathbb E [N_k] = \sum_{t=1}^T \mathbb P(z_t = k).
$$
We also know that
$$
\mathbb P(z_t = k \mid z_{t-1},\dots,z_1) = \frac{\sum_{j=1}^{t-1} 1\{z_j = k\}}{\alpha + t - 1} 1\{k \le K_{t-1}\} + \frac{\alpha}{\alpha+t-1} 1\{ k = K_{t-1}+1 \}.
$$
where $K_{t-1} = \max\{z_1,z_2,\dots,z_{t-1}\}$.
Taking the expectation of both sides
$$
(\alpha+t-1) \mathbb P(z_t = k) = \sum_{j=1}^{t-1} \mathbb P(z_j = k \le K_{t-1}) + \alpha \mathbb P(K_{t-1} = k-1)
$$
For $j \le t-1$,
\begin{align*}
\mathbb P(z_j = k)  &= \mathbb P(z_j = k \le K_{t-1}) + \mathbb P(z_t = k, K_{t-1} < k )  \\
&= \mathbb P(z_j = k \le K_{t-1})
\end{align*}
seeing that if $K_{t-1} < k$ by definition $z_j < k$ for $j \le t-1$.

Letting $\beta_{tk} := \mathbb P(z_t = k)$ and $\gamma_{tk} = \mathbb P(K_t = k)$, we have shown
$$
(\alpha + t - 1) \beta_{tk} = \sum_{j=1}^{t-1} \beta_{jk} + \alpha \gamma_{t-1,k-1}
$$
for $t \ge 2$. By subtracting the case of $t+1$ from that of $t$, we obtain
$$
\beta_{t+1,k} -  \beta_{tk} = \frac{\alpha}{\alpha + t}(\gamma_{t,k-1} - \gamma_{t-1,k-1})
$$
hence
\begin{align*}
\beta_{r+1,k} &= \beta_{2k} + \sum_{t=2}^r \frac{\alpha}{\alpha + t}(\gamma_{t,k-1} - \gamma_{t-1,k-1}), \quad r \ge 2, \\
\beta_{2k} &= \frac{1}{\alpha+1} 1\{k=1\} + \frac{\alpha}{\alpha+1} 1\{k=2\}. \\
\beta_{1k}&= 1\{k=1\}.
\end{align*}

The problem reduces to figuring out $\gamma_{tk}$. But the distribution of $K_t$ is known as the Chinese restaurant table distribution. Its probability mass function is given as
$$
\gamma_{tk} = \frac{\Gamma(\alpha)}{\Gamma(t+\alpha)} |s(t,k)| \alpha^k \cdot 1\{k \le t\}.
$$
where $s(t,k)$ are the Stirling numbers of the first kind.
Putting the pieces together
\begin{align*}
\mathbb E(N_k) &= \sum_{r=1}^T \beta_{rk}  \\
&= \beta_{1k} +  \beta_{2k} + \sum_{r=2}^{T-1} \beta_{r+1,k} \\
&= \beta_{1k} +  (T-2) \beta_{2k} + \sum_{r=2}^{T-1} \sum_{t=1}^r \frac{\alpha}{\alpha + t}(\gamma_{t,k-1} - \gamma_{t-1,k-1}).
\end{align*}

---

Here is a piece of R code verifying this calculation:

```r
# library(gmp) # Needed for the Stirling1 numbers
set.seed(123)
sample_crp = function(n, a) {
  z = vector("numeric")
  z[1] = 1
  for (t in 2:n) {
    zmax = max(z)
    freq = tabulate(z, zmax)
    freq[zmax+1] = a

    z[t] = sample(zmax+1, 1, T, prob = freq)    
  }
  z
}

gam_f = function(t, k, a) {
  if (k > t) return(0)
  return( (gamma(a) / gamma(a + t)) * as.numeric(abs(gmp::Stirling1(t, k))) * a^k )
}
bet_f = function(r, k, a) {
  if (r == 1) {
    return(if (k==1) 1 else 0)
  }
  if (r == 2) {
    if (k==1) return(1/(a+1))
    if (k==2) return(a/(a+1))
    return(0)
  }
  temp = bet_f(2, k, a)
  for (t in 2:(r-1)) {
    temp = temp + a*(gam_f(t, k-1, a) - gam_f(t-1, k-1, a))/(a + t)
  }
  temp
}
N_f = function(n, k, a) sum(sapply(1:n, function(r) bet_f(r, k, a)))

nrep = 2000
n = 20
a = 0.6
X = matrix(nrow = nrep, ncol = n)
for (rep in 1:nrep) {
  X[rep, ] = sample_crp(n, a)  
}

tab = apply(X, 1, FUN = function(z) tabulate(z, n))
rbind(estim=rowMeans(tab)[1:7], true=sapply(1:7, function(k) N_f(n, k, a)))
```

The output is

```
         [,1]     [,2]     [,3]      [,4]      [,5]      [,6]        [,7]
estim 12.8615 4.770500 1.694000 0.5070000 0.1355000 0.0290000 0.002500000
true  12.8750 4.772263 1.670688 0.5159738 0.1329717 0.0277614 0.004646026
```

---

Some details about the above argument:

- What happened when you took the expectation of both sides? In general, the conditional expectation $\mathbb E(X\mid Y)$ is a random variable (a function of $Y$). As a random variable, $\mathbb E(X\mid Y)$ itself has an expectation and we have the general "smoothing" or "tower" property:
  $$
  \mathbb E[\mathbb E(X\mid Y)] = \mathbb E(X).
  $$
  Now take $X = 1_{A}$ to be the indicator of a set, i.e., $X(\omega) = 1_A(\omega) = 1\{\omega \in A\}$. Then, applying the above and noting that the expectation of $1_A$ is the probability of $A$, we have
  $$
  \mathbb E [ \mathbb P(A \mid Y) ] = \mathbb P(A).
  $$
  Note that $\mathbb P(A \mid Y)$ is a random variable and not a deterministic quantity. This type of argument is what is going on in that step.

Comment: Wonderful! Thank you! Yes, you correctly deduced what I mean by table $k$.

Comment: When you write, "Taking the expectation of both sides," your left-hand side is $\mathbb{P}(z_t)$.  Could you clarify what happened there? It seems to me you switched from the conditional distribution $\mathbb{P}(z_t | z_{<t})$ to the marginal distribution $\mathbb{P}(z_t)$, but how is that accomplished by taking an expectation?

Comment: I'm also confused by something right after "We also know that". Your left hand side, the conditional distribution $\mathbb{P}(z_t∣z_{<t})$ is entirely deterministic, right? That is, given $z_{<t}$, we know exactly how much mass to place on each outcome for $z_t$. But you then say to take the expectation of both sides. How does one take the expectation of a deterministic function? Your next step suggests to me that you're treating the indicators as random variables - is this correct? If so, the left hand side is deterministic but the right hand side is random - how can this be?

Comment: @RylanSchaeffer, I have added some comments to end of the answer. Please have a look and let me know if that makes it clear. $\mathbb P (z_t = k \mid z_{<t})$ is not deterministic (in general) but itself a random variable. It is a function of $z_{< t}$ as you can also see from the RHS of the equation. ($z_{<t}$ is random.)

Comment: One quick clarification question: in your expression for $\beta_{r+1, k}$, why is $\beta_{1, k}$ not included in the sum?

Comment: @RylanSchaeffer, the recursive formula that I have derived only holds for $t \ge 2$, hence we can only sum over $t \ge 2$.

Comment: you were very helpful! Could I ask you to take a look at my related question? https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/508645/why-does-chinese-restaurant-table-distribution-look-like-a-gaussian-distribution

Comment: @RylanSchaeffer, added the comment to the posted answer there.