# Why does Chinese Restaurant Table Distribution look like a Gaussian Distribution?

Tags: normal-distribution, stochastic-processes, dirichlet-process, nonparametric-bayes

The [Chinese Restaurant Table Distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chinese_restaurant_process#Distribution) describes the probability distribution for the number of non-empty tables in the Chinese Restaurant Process after $T$ customers have been seated. Specifically, if $K_T$ is the (random) number of non-empty tables after seating $T$ customers in a $CRP(\alpha)$, its PMF is defined as

$$P(K_T = k) = \frac{\Gamma(\alpha)}{\Gamma(\alpha + T)} |S(T, k)| \alpha^k$$

where $k \in \{1, ..., T\}$ and $|S(\cdot, \cdot)|$ are unsigned Stirling numbers of the first kind. I discovered that when I fix $\alpha$ and plot the distribution for increasing values of $T$, the distribution looks more and more like a Gaussian. For alpha=10.01, I plot the distribution from T=1 (red) to T=50 (blue):

[image]

My question is: why does the Chinese Restaurant Table distribution look like a Gaussian distribution for medium-to-large $T$?

Comment: The number of tables is approximately Poisson, which is approximately Gaussian for large rates. You can get a finite sample bound from Le Cam’s Theorem on how close it is to the approximating Poisson.

Comment: I buy that Poisson is approximately Gaussian for large rates, but I'm unfamiliar with the first and third steps. Could you walk me through the derivation?

Comment: Well, the number of tables is $K_T = \sum_{i = 1}^T I(\text{new table at observation $i$})$, and the terms of the sum are independent. You have a lot of options here for showing that it is close to a Gaussian, as it is a sum of independent random variables. For example, if $p_i = \alpha / (\alpha + i)$ is the probability of a new table at observation $i$, then it is easy enough to check that $\sum_i p_i (1 - p_i) = \infty$, after which you can apply [this exercise](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2054592/do-bernoulli-random-variables-always-satisfy-the-lyapunov-condition).

Comment: I buy that the number of tables is $K_T = \sum_{t=1}^T I(\text{new table at observation }t)$. I'm struggling with the next step. The probability of creating a new table at observation $t$ is given by $\alpha/(\alpha + t -1)$, so the expected value of $K_T$ will be $\sum_{t=1}^T \alpha/(\alpha + t -1)$. This looks like a harmonic series, but not exactly, so I'm unclear on how to simplify the sum to get my rate $\lambda$ to apply Le Cam's Theorem. Could you suggest how to simplify the sum?

Comment: There is no way to simplify the sum, and the bound itself doesn't depend on the sum. Although to apply Le Cam's lemma you might need to take $\alpha \downarrow 0$ slowly. Probably the easiest thing to do is actually just to apply the Lyapounov CLT that I linked to in my last comment, if all you care about is the Gaussian part, and skip Le Cam's theorem.

Comment: Also, technically it should be $1 + $ a Poisson, if you go that route, since obviously $K_T \ge 1$. A precise result is given in [this paper](http://www2.stat.duke.edu/~mw/MWextrapubs/West1992alphaDP.pdf).

Comment: @guy thanks for all the help! Do you want to type up a comprehensive answer so I can give you credit? If not, I can write the answer myself and give you credit. Also, as an aside, I think there is a way to simplify the sum. This [note](https://www.gatsby.ucl.ac.uk/~ywteh/research/npbayes/dp.pdf) says that the sum is given exactly by $\alpha (\psi (\alpha + n) - \psi(\alpha))$, where $\psi(\cdot)$ is the Digamma function.

Comment: ok, I added a solution. Vis-a-vis the simplification, it isn't clear to me that the expression $\alpha \{\psi(\alpha + n) - \psi(\alpha)\}$ is actually any simpler; you are just hiding the sum with the special functions :) I actually deliberately did not state this as a simplification.

Comment: @guy thanks again for the help :D :D

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We can apply the Lyapounov CLT to show that $K_T$ is normal for large $T$. Let
$$
  K_T = \sum_{i=1}^T I(\text{new table at $i$}) = \sum_{i=1}^T Z_i.
$$
Then it is well-known that $Z_i \stackrel{\text{ind}}{\sim} \text{Bernoulli}(p_i)$ where $p_i = \alpha / (\alpha + i - 1)$. Now, $\sum_{i=1}^\infty p_i (1 - p_i) = \sum_{i=1}^\infty \frac{\alpha i}{(\alpha + i)^2} = \infty$ by comparison to the harmonic series. Hence we can apply the Lyapnouv CLT to conclude that
$$
\frac{K_T - E(K_T)}{\sqrt{\text{Var}(K_T)}} \to N(0,1)
$$
in distribution, using the argument outlined [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2246876/12806) to verify the Lyapounov condition for Bernoulli random variables.

Comment: Nice answer. One can also use [Berry--Esseen](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Berry%E2%80%93Esseen_theorem) for non-identically distributed variables to get  a quantitative, finite-sample, bound.

Comment: guy & @passerby51, how do you get so good at this stuff? Any tips for learning faster?

Comment: @guy, small nit: I think that $p_i = \alpha/(\alpha + i -1)$, not $p_i = \alpha/(\alpha + i)$?

Comment: @Rylan yes, thanks for the correction. For being "good at this stuff," most of it is just experience. I used to work with DPs a lot.

Comment: @RylanSchaeffer, asking good questions is perhaps the first step (which you are doing fine). Experience (as guy said) helps; it becomes easier over time... practice makes perfect. Other things that come to mind: 1) Reading research papers and seeing how others do it (esp. the really good ones). 2) Doing research: Defining a specific problem and reading and thinking around that. 3) Practice, practice, practice!

Comment: guy and @passerby51,you've both been so helpful, can I ask you two to please take a look at another question? https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/512741/reason-for-poisson-distribution-in-indian-buffet-process